# How to correctly verify a MX record?

Tags: c#

I'm using [DNSClient](https://dnsclient.michaco.net/) to verify mail exchange domains by doing:

```
var address = new MailAddress(valueAsString);

var lookup = new LookupClient();
var result = lookup.Query(address.Host, QueryType.MX);

var record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
```

However, domains like `icoud.com` or `googglemail.com` return answers but they should be incorrect mail exchanges.

Is there a better or additional way to make sure that a domain is really a mail exchange?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `MxRecords()` instead of `ARecords`.

Comment: There is no MxRecords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `MxRecord` only, which inherits from `DnsResourceRecord`. You can use LINQ for this.

```cs
var record = result.Answers.OfType<MxRecord>.FirstOrDefault();
```

There is also [an extension method](https://dnsclient.michaco.net/docs/System.Linq.RecordCollectionExtension.html#System_Linq_RecordCollectionExtension_MxRecords_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_DnsClient_Protocol_DnsResourceRecord__) for this apparently

```cs
var record = result.Answers.MxRecords().FirstOrDefault();
```